# Does Tor use Garlic Routing?

Tags: onion-routing

I came across the garlic routing section (8.1.1) in Roger's Master's thesis: https://dspace.mit.edu/bitstream/handle/1721.1/86475/46861930-MIT.pdf?sequence=2. I am not sure whether current Tor version is using garlic routing or just onion routing? Please correct me if I say anything wrong.

Answer (score 1):

No, Tor does not use garlic routing as defined here.

Comment: here? please fix the URL

Comment: The URL you provided defines garlic routing. Tor doesn't do that.

Comment: That is Roger's Thesis, the origin of Tor design.

Comment: I don't think Roger's thesis is the origin of Tor design, but that's not important. What's important is that **the answer is NO Tor does not use garlic routing**

Answer (score 0):

> A node then finds **several garlic bulbs** to transmit, instead of the normal single onion.

No. Currently, Tor is based on a strict (original) onion routing model, in which one stream can only be attached onto one and only one circuit.